# angular/express api/mongodb update issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

working with a full MEAN stack. 
trying to write data to a "notes" array in my mongodb document id #1.

mongo document:

```
> db.contacts.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a294af85e96746421bf35f1"),
"id" : 1,
"type" : "dealer",
"name" : "ken yoder",
"company" : "kens sales",
"phone" : "817-403-9767",
"notes" : [
    {
        "date" : "Thu Dec 07 2017 08:15:37 GMT-0600 (CST)",
        "by" : "@me",
        "note" : "this is a note"
    },
    {
        "date" : "Thu Dec 07 2017 08:16:31 GMT-0600 (CST)",
        "by" : "@donny",
        "note" : "bla bla bla mumford and sons"
    },
    {
        "date" : "Thu Dec 07 2017 08:34:03 GMT-0600 (CST)",
        "by" : "@ken",
        "note" : "test with another note"
    },
    {
        "date" : "Thu Dec 07 2017 08:34:29 GMT-0600 (CST)",
        "by" : "@ken",
        "note" : "test with another notey note note"
    }
],
"setNotes" : {
    "date" : "Thu Dec 07 2017 10:52:09 GMT-0600 (CST)",
    "by" : "@kale",
    "note" : "hhsdihufiudhsiuhdshuifds"
}
}
```

express code:

```
app.get('/newNote/:noteFor/:noteCount/:noteBy/:note/', function (req, res) {
        var setNotes = "notes."+req.params.noteCount;
        db.collection('contacts').update({ id:req.params.noteFor }, { $set: { setNotes : {date: Date(), by: req.params.noteBy, note: req.params.note} }}, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("notefor: "+req.params.noteFor+" noteCount: "+setNotes+" noteBy: "+req.params.noteBy+" note: "+req.params.note);
                console.log(res.result.nModified + " for " + req.params.noteFor + " updated");
        });
});
```

if i run this code as it sits, i get nothing, no insert, no errors. 
- if i change the update id from "req.params.id" to "1", i get an insert but...
- instead of using my "setNotes" variable (which outputs "notes.4") for the $set identifier, it created a new object called "setNotes".

```
API URL: /newNote/1/4/@kale/this is a note test
```

Comment: oh wow im stupid... ok that fixes that. lol Thank you. what about the "setNotes" var? is it possible to pass the name and count to the $set that way?

Comment: updated this code:
    id:req.params.noteFor

still not inserting.

Comment: app.get('/newNote/:noteFor/:noteCount/:noteBy/:note/', function (req, res) {
        var setNotes = "notes."+req.params.noteCount;
        db.collection('contacts').update({ id:req.params.noteFor }, { $set: { setNotes : {date: Date(), by: req.params.noteBy, note: req.params.note} }}, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("notefor: "+req.params.noteFor+" noteCount: "+setNotes+" noteBy: "+req.params.noteBy+" note: "+req.params.note);
                console.log(res.result.nModified + " for " + req.params.noteFor + " updated");
        });
});

Comment: ok i edited it...

Comment: i just changed the "id" in my mongo document to a string and it started working... apparently it didnt like the integer. so its writing to the mongodb now, but the "setnotes" var is still not right. i'm trying to save these note objects in an array, to do so the syntax needs to be `$set { "notes.4": { date:Date().... etc etc` . i'm counting the notes in the ui and sending it back through `:noteCount` ... but its using my var as the $set name instead of my vars' value as the $set name.

Comment: i just created the "setNotes" var to try to print "notes.4" as my $set name. "notes" is the array in my mongo document, "4" is the number of objects in the array already.

Comment: i want to add a 5th document... then the code will need to be `$set { "notes.5": { date:Date().... etc ` to add the 6th note... then the code will need to be `$set { "notes.6": { date:Date().... etc ` to add the 7th note... and so on. i dont know the syntax to use that `"notes.4"` name dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will just add a new document everytime to `notes` array:

```
db.collection('contacts').update({ id:req.params.noteFor }, { 
          $push: { 
                   notes : {date: Date(), by: req.params.noteBy, note: req.params.note} 
                 }
          }, function(err, res) {
        //code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

first read express api basics, http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html. from question  there is noting in req.params.id , instead of id req.params contain four keys (noteFor, noteCount, noteBy and note ). also you override res varible by result of query notice   **function(err, res) {.........**

```
 db.collection('contacts').update(
    { id:req.params.id }, 
    { $set: 
        { setNotes : {date: Date(), by: req.params.noteBy, note: req.params.note} }
    },
    {   
        // if noting found then stop create new document with values of $set 
        upsert:false
        //  result should be updated document  
        new:true
    }, 
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(err, result)
    })
```

Comment: updated this code:
    id:req.params.noteFor

still not inserting.

Comment: mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
mongoose.set('debug', true); and post debug query from console

Comment: what does that mean?